# Printing results in playwright python eg. print(result)

Tags: python, automation, playwright-python

I just learnt playwright python and wanted to know how one can print the results of a page to the terminal. I have tried printing to the terminal in the playwright function but it does nothing. Also how do you check if an element is in the DOM and return true or false?

this is what i am trying to do in pseudo-code.

```
if( this selector is on the page ){
    print("selector on page")
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import logging
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

if page.locator('Your Locator CSS/Xpath').is_visible():
    LOGGER.info('selector on page')
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your code?

Comment: Also, parentheses are not required around the if-statement in Python.